# Email: how to set a name of the embedded image in C# / System.Mail?

Tags: c#, html-email, mime-message

I'm trying to send email with embedded images in it from C#. When I receive this email in Gmail, embedded images do not have proper names - instead, they are displayed as "noname" - see screenshot below

[image]

Here is how I embed images into email:

```
foreach (var objimage in images)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(objimage.ImageBytes);
    var lr = new LinkedResource(ms, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    lr.ContentId = "Photo_" + (++i).ToString();
    lstImages.Add(lr);

    body += string.Format("<img src='cid:{0}' alt='{1}' name='{1}' title='{1}' />", lr.ContentId, objimage.ImageName);
}
```

looking at this question: [How to stop embedded images in email being displayed as attachments by GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040358/how-to-stop-embedded-images-in-email-being-displayed-as-attachments-by-gmail) - and comparing body of my email, it looks like i need to set Content-Type field to be

Content-Type: image/jpeg; **name="my image name.png"**"

whereas currently my email looks like this:

```
----boundary_3_d581d04c-d294-4dc5-971e-785a678fbd12
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <Photo_1>
```

any idea how I can do this with C# and System.Mail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

well, answer turns out to be very simple:

```
lr.ContentType.Name = "my image name.jpg";
```

credits to [Send html email with embedded image and plain text with same image as attachment in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573944/send-html-email-with-embedded-image-and-plain-text-with-same-image-as-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

if image is not coming in IE use below 
 linkedResource = new LinkedResource(src, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
//abbukmailer.com

Answer (score -2):

For attachments

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; fileName=<Your file name>
```

Regarding to RFC

For linked resource must be something simillar